# Share feedback with image on Facebook wall in Windows Phone 8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 application, I've integrated Facebook by using the below information. And I have successfully posted the message on my wall.

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application

Now I want to share the feedback with image and URL on Facebook wall. For reference please see in the below image.

[image]

How could I achieve this in a Windows Phone 8 Application?

Comment: if your phone is synced with facebook account then you can use MediaShareTask...

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Thanks for your reply. My Phone is not sync with face book. How could I share link or give feed-back with image. I'm looking forward for your response.